# Animate borders (border-left, border-top) of box on hover

Tags: html, css

I would like to animate two borders on hover specifically border-left and border-top. After doing some research it does not seem you can actually "animate" the borders themselves so you have to create a "line" which on hover should have its width set to 100% to have the same effect.

I know how to do this with underlining menu items, but I would like to do it with this box I'm trying to create. 
Specifically on hover (while maintaining the css effects already written up)

1) border-left should extend to the top and right after that-> 2) border-top extending from the left to the right.

Also was wondering how I can choose which borders to extend if I don't want to to just do border-left or border-top.

This is my box thus far (unfortunately nothing with animating borders):

CSS:

```
#txt{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size:2vw;
}
#box{
    position:fixed;
    top:25%;
    left:25%;
    height:20vw;
    width:20vw;
    border-right: 2px solid deepskyblue;
    border-bottom: 2px solid deepskyblue;
    background-color:black;
    color:ghostwhite;
}
#box:hover{
    color:deepskyblue;
    transition: color 0.25s ease;
}
#box:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    transform: scale(0, 0);
    transform-origin:bottom right;
    background: ghostwhite;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: transform 0.25s ease;
}
#box:hover::after{
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    color:deepskyblue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="box">
<span id="txt">TEXT</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `#txt` element as large as the parent box and then use pseudo-element on that to make "borders" and animate the dimensions of those pseudo-elements.

If you add a `transiton-delay` in I think you can get the effect you are after.

```css
#txt {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#box {
  font-size: 2vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 1em;
  left: 40vw;
  height: 20vw;
  width: 20vw;
  background-color: black;
  color: ghostwhite;
}

#box:hover {
  color: deepskyblue;
  transition: color 0.25s ease;
}

#box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(0, 0);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  background: ghostwhite;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
}

#box:hover::after {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  color: deepskyblue;
}

#txt::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#txt::before {
  width: 0;
  border-left: 2px solid deepskyblue;
  transition: height .25s .5s ease;
}

#txt:hover::before {
  height: 100%;
}

#txt::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid deepskyblue;
  transition: width 0.25s .75s ease;
}

#txt:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <span id="txt">TEXT</span>
</div>
```